# Could H2O have a 4th phase rather than 3?

Tags: water

I just finished a book which is hard to argue: "The Fourth Phase of Water" by Dr. Gerald H Pollack. He states there's a negative layer of H2O (which is termed the 'Exclusion Zone') which develops all around the bulk water. The bulk water is positively charged.

If this is possible, does it explain how ice forms on the surface layer of a large body of water where the negatively charged molecules are then exposed to the positively charged air?

Comment: Why is it hard to argue?

Comment: @JonCuster - Because this appears to be pure crackpottery. Voting to close.

Comment: @DavidHammen - hence making no it pretty easy to argue against the concept! And that is even not considering all the ice allotropes...

Comment: It is not quite understood as to why the earth as well as our own blood cells register a negative charge. Pollock's argument is that the 4th Phase of water surrounds the positively charged bulk. So the earth puts off negative charge due to EZ water. I'm going to pursue this in spite of the fact there is going to be little discussion here on this topic.

Comment: @Necromancer Earth interacts with neutrinos, which turn into electrons or light. Probably what keeps the core melted after billions of years.

Answer (score 4):

Pollack’s book appears to be garbage, according to the answer to [this Chemistry Stack Exchange question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/5925/ez-water-fraud-or-breakthrough).

However, water does indeed have more than three phases. In fact, it has at least 19 distinct phases!

In particular, [water has at least 17 solid crystalline phases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice#Phases), which form under different conditions of temperature and pressure. Almost all naturally occurring ice on Earth’s surface is the variety called ice $1_h$, with tiny bits of ice $1_c$ mixed in.

There are also some apparently reputable theories involving water having [two liquid phases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water#States), but that’s less well established than the different phases of ice.

Comment: copy-paste from linked thread: Bought the book, I put it to test, considering: hydrophilic surface creates the stack of EZ layers. made a rack of microscope cover glasses 0.13mm thick separated by de-phased ones to make 0.13mm gaps, (ideally EZ-water forming between sheets and flow should "filter/purify" water). But didn't observe ANY exclusion zone at all. Random particles would just fall to the outer glass. Food dye didn't react at all. This glass is hydrophilic AF BTW, water droplets extend to max over it... So I'm confused, slowly inclined to call scam. hints/thoughts on home made EZ?

Comment: Although I did observe before, that small (~1-0.5mm diameter) air bubbles after shaking the water do project a falling tubular structure that reflect light a bit differently, probably thin as hair though... So I'm not sure why my glass experiment failed miserably. 
I think the "phase" related debate is dumb. It should be just (dis?)proven if EZ actually forms or not. If it does, it doesn't matter how we call it. What matters is that it'd be a good infra-red to polarized water (battery) converter. Or enable a nice water desalinization/filter technique.